# Mostrar GIF de espera mientras ajax realiza la peticion

Tags: javascript, ajax, modal

Tengo el Siguiente codigo HTML:

```
 <div id="detalles-modalE" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Detalle de Pedido.-</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body edit-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y el siguiente codigo JS que llama al modal y envia los datos a traves de ajax:

```
$('#detalles-modalE').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

var $modal = $(this),
//-> aqui llamo a mis variables ->//

$.ajax({
 cache: false,
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'miurl',
 data: {misdatos},
 success: function(data) {
  $modal.find('.edit-content').html(data);
 } 
}) 
})
```

Lo que necesito, es que mientras se realiza la peticion ajax se muestre una gif de cargando, pero dentro de la ventana moda.
He leido y buscado varios ejemplos, pero ningun ha funcionado.
Alguien tiene una idea de como poder hacer eso?. Les agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientacion al respecto. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de como lo puedes hacer. Lo que debes hacer básicamente es incorporar una imagen en el contenido antes de realizar la consulta. Luego una vez obtenido el resultado o cuando creas que sea correcto eliminarla, debes limpiar el contenido de "edit-content" y cargar la nueva información. En el siguiente ejemplo uso un timmer para simular la consulta y la respuesta obtenida después de 5 segundos. Deberías mover esas lineas de código al Success de tu consulta. Saludos!

```js
$('#detalles-modalE').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

var $modal = $(this);
//-> aqui llamo a mis variables ->//
// antes de realizar la consulta cargamos nuestro gif
let imgUrl= "https://media.giphy.com/media/y1ZBcOGOOtlpC/200.gif";
$('.edit-content').html('<img src="'+imgUrl+'" alt="cargando">');
//
/*$.ajax({
 cache: false,
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'miurl',
 data: '',
 success: function(data) {
  $modal.find('.edit-content').html(data);
 } 
}) */

// vamos a simular una demora de 5 segundo y una respuesta de nuestra consulta. Esto lo deberias hacer en el SUCCESS.

setTimeout(function(){ 
//Limpiamos el contenido de "edit-content" eliminando la imangen antes de cargar los nuevos datos
$('.edit-content').html('');
}, 5000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detalles-modalE">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
 <div id="detalles-modalE" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Detalle de Pedido.-</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body edit-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: a lo que me refería es que lo primero que debes hacer en el success es remover la imagen con `$('.edit-content').html('')`. Solo eso

Comment: estimado, muchisimas gracias, adapte mi codigo con tu idea propuesta y funciono impecable. Un abrazo y muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda. Saludos.